# How to use FB Javascript SDK Event Subscribe

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I've recently implemented FB Javascript SDK for a mobile web app and am playing with their event subscription code:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', handleStatusChange);
```

I notice that handleStatusChange is called when I log in into facebook through my app.  However, if I open another browser tab, go to facebook.com and log out the function isn't called.

I was expecting it to be called.  Am I wrong? I thought the point of this function was to monitor changes that were not necessarily within the purview of my app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> auth.authResponseChange - fired when the authResponse changes

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getAuthResponse/

This would be when a users add or removes a permission, in our flows we are supposed to provide away for a users to remove each permission and authResponse allows us to monitor.

Comment: Does authResponse change when you logout from facebook in a different tab?

Comment: good question i am not sure, can you test that real fast and let us know?

Comment: well i tried it and its not firing so i presume its not built for that